# Host key verification failed in Jenkins, working inside Docker

Tags: git, shell, docker, jenkins, ssh

I am integrating Jenkins for a build system and the Jenkins is installed in my local machine. The build is running in docker container and I need to checkout a db migration repo inside the container. Foe SSH authentication, I am executing a shell script, which like the following :

```
mkdir -p ~/.ssh
touch ~/.ssh/id_rsa

echo "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
KEY HERE
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----" > ~/.ssh/id_rsa

chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

After running this, I can clone the code inside the Docker container, but not from the pipeline or another shell script which does the checkout. It is returning error

> Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '192.30.253.113' to the list of known hosts.
>       Permission denied (publickey).
>       fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>       
>       Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

The key is added correctly and working from inside docker. How can I make this work from the shell script ?

Comment: Maybe the user in the container is `root` and without docker it's `jenkins`? Are you trying to login as `root`? Have you specified the username for the `ssh` command?

Comment: Why don't you just add the ssh key to the Jenkins credentials? You can then use it in the pipeline with `withCredentials` ? :)

Comment: @StephenKing Yes, the user `root` in container. I am not doing `SSH`, I am doing `git clone` only